# Function doesn't go into for loop

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

I'm trying to write my own function, which gets 2 strings, and says if the first one contains the second one as a word (meaning the word is surrounded by " " or ",") When I test it for the strings "squawk, squeal" and "squawk", it's `ok`, it goes into the second for loop (the one with the `j`) and outputs 1, but for "squeal" it doesn't go into the `j` loop at all. Here's the code I have so far:

```
bool containsMeaning(string bigMeaning, string smallMeaning)

{

unsigned int smallCounter = 0;
unsigned int matchBeginning = 0;
unsigned int matchEnd = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bigMeaning.size() - smallMeaning.size() + 1; i++)
{
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;
    smallCounter = 0;
    if (bigMeaning[i] == smallMeaning[0])
    {
        matchBeginning = 0;
        cout << "I'm inside the if " << i << endl;
        for (unsigned int j = i; j < smallMeaning.size(); j++)
        {
            cout << "big char " << bigMeaning[j] << " small char " << smallMeaning[smallCounter] << endl;
            if (bigMeaning[j] != smallMeaning[smallCounter])
            {
                cout << "I want to break free" << j << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                matchEnd = j;
                smallCounter++;
                cout << "j = " << j << " smallcoutner = " << smallCounter << endl;
            }
        }
        if (smallCounter == smallMeaning.size() &&
           (matchBeginning == 0 || bigMeaning[matchBeginning - 1] == ' ' || bigMeaning[matchBeginning - 1] == ',')
        && (bigMeaning[matchEnd + 1] == '\0' || bigMeaning[matchEnd + 1] == ' ' || bigMeaning[matchEnd + 1] == ','))
            return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: Thought about using a debugger and stepping through the code?

Comment: Which anomalies did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: I marked it at the `cout << big char` line, when I type squeal it does into the first word squawk for 3 chars, stops and never goes into the second word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the conditions in the second `for` loop. There is a logical error in what you are doing there. You set `j = i` with the aim of having a counter which will iterate over both strings comparing them character by character. However, `i` in the first for loop iterates over the bigger string, and there is no reason for it to be less than the size of the smaller string, which is what you are assuming in the second for loop in the `j < smallMeaning.size()` command.

Instead of that, your `for` loop should `for (int j = i; j < i + smallMeaning.size(); j++)`.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much, I feel so embarrassed :(